# Why is my JSON parsing not working in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I tried lots of different parsing methods and this one is the best but i am getting the "error parsing" when I actually parse the JSON. I also added the structs I used to parse it. The API is newsapi and I don't know why the parsing isn't working

```
struct Newsfeed: Codable {

    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}
    
struct Article: Codable {

    let source: [String:String]
    let author: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String
    let content: String

}




private func getData(from url: String, label: UILabel) {
    
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Something went wrong")
            return
        }
        var results: Newsfeed?
        do {
            results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Newsfeed.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
           print("Error parsing")
        }
        guard let json = results else {
            return
        }
            
        print(json.articles[0].content)
        label.text = json.articles[0].source["name"]
   
        
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Replace `print("Error parsing")` with `print("Error parsing: \(error)")` to see what the error actually is.

Comment: Add Your JSON as an example

Comment: I printed the error and the value of the source dict in the Article struct can be nil so what can i do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the fields in the JSON that NewsAPI is providing can be null. When you're decoding JSON with codable you must specify optional properties if this is the case.

Also, the `source` property is an object so I created one to let codable know how to parse it as well.

This example seems to work!

```
import Foundation

struct Newsfeed: Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    let url: URL?
    let urlToImage: URL?
    let content: String?
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}


private func getData(from url: String) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Something went wrong")
            return
        }
        var results: Newsfeed?
        do {
            results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Newsfeed.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error parsing \(error)")
        }
        guard let json = results else {
            return
        }

        print(json.articles[0].content)

    }).resume()
}

let apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
let urlString = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=\(apiKey)"
getData(from: urlString)
```